# Output custom RenderModel for all Umbraco 4.10 MVC routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, umbraco

Is there any way of either overriding the default RenderMvcController to output a custom RenderModel for every route. It's possibly by hijacking routes but I want to put some custom data which will be used on every page.

For example, on an e-commerce site every page displays the basket information. Ideally this would be available in the RenderModel for every view. Is there a way of changing the default Controller to a custom one which will output an extended render model with a Basket attribute?

**Update:**

This is now supported in Umbraco 6.1.0+ the documentation is at the end of this page: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/custom-controllers

Comment: I assume this is Umbraco v4.10?

Comment: Hi, Yes it is v4.10, I've updated the question to make that clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I would consider is instead of trying to crowbar custom data into Umbraco's default page model, consider having a `BasketSurfaceController` and rendering the basket contents to the screen using `@Html.Action("HeaderDisplay", "BasketSurface")` or something similar. This way you could keep the view model independent and have it displayed as part of the `_Layout.cshtml` or on the specific pages you need.

Also using this approach, you can maintain a collection of specific basket-related views all fed by the same Controller with a clean separation from Umbraco's model.

See the documentation on [Child Actions](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/mvc/child-actions/) for further info.

**Update:**

On re-reading the documentation, I can see that this is possible in 4.10+ and quite easily. The [documentation is here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/custom-controllers) but in a nutshell you can override requests to each document type or override all requests by replacing the default controller.

Although I would still advocate the `ChildAction` approach for this particular scenario, overriding the document type controller to pass down a custom view model is ideal for passing a pre-formed model that is specific to the page (e.g. a blog entry with comments. associated categories) and/or passing a model that contains data that isn't available from the page itself but is required on each page (e.g. the site name, domain, locale, global tracking/affiliate code, metadata).

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, unfortunately this means that I'm loading the basket each time it's used in an action. In a standard MVC project I'd load it in once and then it would be available in a view model. But it doesn't look like I can do this with the current MVC implementation in Umbraco 4.10

Comment: You would be loading the basket each time even if it was in Umbraco's page model as this is created on a request-by-request basis. I think ChilsAction approach at least means that you can separate the logic and build the output from the session if db calls are a concern.

Comment: But I may use the basket in several different places in a single request, for example viewing the basket page may have it in the header, the main page content and possibly footer

Comment: Don't forget that a controller instance is created per-request, so you could possibly allow the basket information be held and access in the Context.Items collection. Alternatively, use the Session, TempData object or even extend the Controller itself.